# JScrollPane now showing its viewport

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, viewport

I am making an application with Java Swing and i have a problem. I have made a Tabbed Panel, which need to hold a simple panel, and a scroll-panel. The simple panel is working fine but in my scroll-panel i can only see the scrollbars, but not the viewport, my code is as follows:

ContentPane

```
public class ContentPane extends JTabbedPane {
    private InfoPanel ip;
    ScrollPanel sp;

    public InfoPanel getIp() {
        return ip;
    }

    public ContentPane(GraphPanel gp) {
        this.sp = new ScrollPanel(gp);
        this.sp.setViewportView(gp);

        this.addTab("Graph", this.sp);
        this.ip = new InfoPanel(gp);
        this.addTab("Info", ip);
    }
}
```

ScrollPanel

```
public class ScrollPanel extends JScrollPane {
    public ScrollPanel(GraphPanel gp){
        this.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        this.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        this.repaint();
    }
}
```

GraphPanel

```
public GraphPanel(StatusBar sb) {
    this.sb = sb;
    zoomLevel = 5;
    sm = new Simulation();
    mh = new MouseHandler(this, sm);
    this.addMouseListener(mh);
    this.setBackground(new Color(240, 165, 98));        
    this.repaint();
}
```

Since i don't get any errors or exceptions, i am now completely lost in which aproach to take.

Comment: I can add to this that i have a MouseListener in GraphPanel which still registers my mouse clicks in the panel, but still nothing is showing in there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not subclass JScrollPane, it is not necessary.

But if you do so, don't forget to add the component to the scrollpane.

In your subclass you are **not** adding the GraphPanel to the scroll pane.:

```
public class ScrollPanel extends JScrollPane {
    public ScrollPanel(GraphPanel gp){

         // ::::  HERE ::: you are not doing anything with gp 
         // like this.setViewPort( gp ) or something like that

        this.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        this.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        this.repaint();
    }
}
```

Try:

```
public class ScrollPanel extends JScrollPane {
    public ScrollPanel(GraphPanel gp){
        super( gp );
        .... etc ...
```

And have GraphPanel extend JComponent or JPanel

Comment: I added the graphpanel as viewport in the ContentPane class, and i tried this too, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: oohh , yeap I have just seen that part... let me try other thing.

Comment: Dude, that worked, can you in a few words explain what i did wrong? Thank you so much :)

Comment: Oh and also, my scrollpanel doesn't really know when it needs to scroll, where should i put an option in for this?

Comment: Look again, did it really worked ? Because probable the other tab is not working very well.

Comment: The other tab is working fine, it is not supposed to be a scroll-panel, just a simple panel. But the graph panel is still not scrolling when the graph is bigger than the scrollpanel..

Comment: I have just modified the code and it scrolls well. I don't know what the graph panel but I have added a JLabel see: http://pastebin.com/f5f69fe80

Comment: One thing is true, if GraphPanel is a JComponent ( or a subclass ) and you try to render in two different places ( say GraphTab and InfoTab ) it will show well only in one of them.

Comment: Okay, by using that i have a scrollpanel that will scroll, but the panel will be on top of the graph, and my graph is a variable size, do i need to specify the minimumsize of the graphpanel somewhere?

Comment: Finally, see the if you're defining preferredSize and/or minimSize. That's what the JScrollPane takes to know when to show the scrolls bar.

Comment: "do i need to specify the minimumsize "  yeap, I think prefferredSize is enough, that is what the JScoll takes to know if it should or not show the scrolls, "How much is visible and how much should it scroll"

Comment: If your graph is variable size you'll have to implement the Scrollable Interface that is a little bit tricky.

Comment: I think i just found a solution with just varying the PreferredSize when i change something in the GraphPanel

Comment: Yeap. In the code in pastebin, notice the JLabel has a big preffered size... :)  I'm glad you have make this thing to work.

Comment: I am glad you helped me make this thing work :). About that Scrollable  interface, how difficult is it? Cause this approach i took, it is not working :P

Comment: I have implemented the methods in the interface now, but they don't seem to ever be called :/